# Conver binary tree to MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, tree, submenu, menustrip

I have a `List<MenuReponse>` menus like:

[image: MenuResponse class]

How can I convert it to `MenuStrip` when I load the Form like:

[image: form main load]

Comment: Does the `List<MenuReponse>` contain the items of the `feature` menu only or the other menu items (`test` - `test`) are also included?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply using recursion with data structure logic. Before going to answer the question, I have some suggestions:

- It's not a binary tree, it's ordinary tree
- Should use english naming parameters in SO to get fullly support, besides that, it's even not violate the naming convention rules :)

I'm assuming that your model like:

```
public class MenuResponse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MenuResponse Parent { get; set; }
    public List<MenuResponse> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

Create instance root MenuResponse which won't show on the menu. This root would be a combination tree for easier finding.

```
    MenuResponse root = new MenuResponse();
    root.Name = "Root";
    root.Childrens = yourListMenuResponse; // Attach your list here
    CreateMenuStrips(root);
```

`CreateMenuStrips` creates menu on top line, `CreateDropDownMenus` creates item using recursion

```
    public void CreateMenuStrips(MenuResponse root)
    {
        foreach (var child in root.Childrens)
        {
            var menu = new ToolStripMenuItem(child.Name);
            CreateDropDownMenus(child, menu);
            baseMenuStrip.Items.Add(menu);
        }
    }

    public void CreateDropDownMenus(MenuResponse menuRes, ToolStripMenuItem menu)
    {
        if (menuRes.Childrens == null)
            return;

        foreach (var child in menuRes.Childrens)
        {
            var childMenu = menu.DropDownItems.Add(child.Name);
            CreateDropDownMenus(child, childMenu as ToolStripMenuItem);
        }
    }
```

Result

[image: Result]

---

I implemented the data function for anyone would like to test

```
public static class MenuUtils
{
    public static MenuResponse AddChildMenu(this MenuResponse menu, string name)
    {
        if (menu.Childrens is null)
            menu.Childrens = new List<MenuResponse>();

        MenuResponse newMenu = new MenuResponse();
        newMenu.Name = name;
        newMenu.Parent = menu;

        menu.Childrens.Add(newMenu);
        return newMenu;
    }

    public static MenuResponse AddSiblingMenu(this MenuResponse menu, string name)
    {
        return menu.Parent.AddChildMenu(name);
    }
}
```

Create data

```
    MenuResponse root = new MenuResponse();
    root.Name = "Root";
    root.Childrens = new List<MenuResponse>(); 


    root.AddChildMenu("Feature")
            .AddChildMenu("Feature 1")
            .AddSiblingMenu("Feature 2")
                .AddChildMenu("Feature 2.1").Parent
            .AddSiblingMenu("Feature 3")
                .AddChildMenu("Feature 3.1")
                .AddSiblingMenu("Feature 3.2")
                    .AddChildMenu("Feature 3.2.1");

    root.AddChildMenu("Test")
            .AddChildMenu("Test 1")
                .AddChildMenu("Test 1.1")
                    .AddChildMenu("Test 1.1.1")
                    .AddSiblingMenu("Test 1.1.2");
```